# Angular2 custom npm package

Tags: angular, npm

I'd like to write a npm module for an authentication service I use in several apps.
I took a look at other packages but couldnt' find a big difference.

**My Module Section::**

my Package.json:

```
{
 "name": "myApi-services",
 "version": "1.0.0-11",
 "main": "index.js",    //referring to the compiled js file from index.ts
 "dependencies": {
 "@angular/common": "2.1.0",
 "@angular/core": "^2.1.0",
 "@angular/http": "^2.1.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.0",
 "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.25",
 "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
 "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
 }
}
```

my Index.ts

```
export { MyAuthService} from "./authenticate"
```

my Authenticate class

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Config } from './config'

export class Authenticate {

constructor(private http:Http, private authUrl:string) {
    this.authUrl = Config.authUrl;
}

public login(username:string, password:string): void {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    this.http.post(this.authUrl, {}, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                this.storeToken(response.json().token);
            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('Request Complete')
        );
}

private storeToken(token: string):void{
    localStorage.setItem('apiservices_token', token);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('apiservices_token'))
}
}
```

**My Import Section::**

package.json

```
"depenencies":{
  "MyApi-services": "file:/// .... "
}
```

The import works, the module gets importes to the node_modules folder

app.module.ts

```
import { Authenticate } from 'myApi-services'
@NgModule({
  imports:[ Authenticate ]
})
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Authenticate } from 'myApi-services'

...

constructor(private auth: Authenticate){}

private login():void{
   auth.login('me', '12345');
}

....
```

One of the errors thrown by the browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Authenticate' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```

This error is caused by imorting the module. Declaring it as provider doesn't work either. The error is the same.

Does anyone know how to create own custom plugins for angular2 and how to inject them correctely?

Comment: Try to use Authenticate in Providers not imports, imports is mainly for modules declarations.

Comment: It throws the same execption. Can it be a problem declaring class variables in the constructor of the module?

Answer (score 0):

The problem were the constructor parameters in my module:

```
constructor(
     private http:Http, 
     private authUrl:string) {
   this.authUrl = Config.authUrl;
```

}

As I declared them directly in the class, the module worked:

```
export class Authenticate {
      http: Http;
      authUrl:strin;

      constructor(){
          console.log("constructor without params");
      }
 }
```

A angular2 npm modules don't seem to like params in the constructor.

Furter (as Michał said): The module has to placed at the providers, not at the imports.